# Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED) OpenVpn connecting refused by server side

Tags: connection, port, firewall, openvpn

OpenVpn Gurus,

I  successively  configured my Openvpn server.ovpn and client.ovpn files and all other required certification files. And I could load them on my server computer. Please first have a  look on my  files:

**Server file**

[image]

And I make sure that my corresponding configuration on  client file is correct.

I could load the server.ovpn in the right way:

[image]

[image]

***Now is the problem:***

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 OpenVPN 2.2.1 Win32-MSVC++ [SSL] [LZO2] built on Jul  1 2011

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 LZO compression initialized

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '69109d17'

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'c0103fa8'

Wed Dec 12 06:04:25 2012 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 123.149.197.134:1440

Wed Dec 12 06:04:26 2012 TCP: connect to 123.149.197.134:1440 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection refused (WSAECONREFUSED)

I have a simple guess that it is about the permission on specific port on the server computer, but on the third picture, it looks like the 1194 port is listening to the connection from the outside world.

The server and client computer actually in the same room  so the ping should be very good, around 3ms shown in the result of "ping serverIpaddress". However, it could not connect to the port 1194 and show me that here is  some refuse condition on the server computer side. The server computer is on win xp. Do I need add the 1194 port as  an exception on the firewall>

Thanks lot at first.